# Can I do a factorial ANOVA on non-normal data?

Tags: normal-distribution, anova

If I am comparing the effect of age, sex, location (numerical) on various numerical parameters, but one of these responses are not normally distributed, can I still do a factorial ANOVA?

I can't do a Kruskal Wallis test as I am comparing so many variables.

EDIT: Anderson-Darling normality test gave a p-value of <0.005

Comment: What exactly isn’t normal?

Comment: One of my responses isn't distributed normally.